# Belkin QODE thin for iPad mini reprogramming

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, remap, ipad-mini, bluetooth-keyboard

I just got belkin qode bluetooth keyboard for ipad mini, but it is in french. Layout of the keys is ok, I remember where which letter is, but when I press M it types (in my language - czech) letter "Ů". When switched to english keyboard on iPad and M is pressed, it types ";" ... Is there any chance on reprogramming the keyboard itself or remapping it in iPad?
Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question. Have you checked the product's User Manual or the manufacturer's support website ?

Comment: Yes, nothing helpful is there. Thats why I need to reprogram the keyboards firmware, if possible.